# JavaScript load Images in an Array and Show in Image Source

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, setattribute

I created an array of images

```
function initialize(){
//add our 10 images to our array
imgArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "img1.jpg");
imgArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "img2.jpg");
imgArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "img3.jpg");

}
var totalImgs = imgArray.length;
```

I then create a function that is linked with a  in my html file:

```
<button id="startButton" onclick="startImage()">Start</button>

function startImage(){

    document.getElementById("pic").setAttribute("src", imgArray[0].src);
}
```

My image tag : `<img id="pic" src="" height="300" width="500" border="0" alt="image">`

This fails to update my img object, i used firebug to look at the DOM and my array is being populated properly but the img src is not be set?

Comment: is imageNum defined? If it's not defined then imageNum++ will return NaN.. also, is imgArray defined? if it's not, then imgArray[n] will throw exception. And you probably should use imgArray.push(new imageItem(imageDir + "armory.jpg"))..

Comment: in startImage() you call imgArray[0] - but imgArray is not recognized from inside the function!

Comment: What is `imageItem`? Are you certain it returns an `HTMLImageElement`? And are you certain your `imageDir` is correct?

Comment: You may need to provide more details so we can help (i.e. more of your code).  Otherwise, I have to ask questions like did you call initialize()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is incomplete. You need to show what the `imageItem` constructor does (and it's convention to use a capital letter for the first character in a constructor), so:

```
function ImageItem(src) {
  this.image = new Image();
  this.src = src.
}
```

should do the job here. You also seem to want `imgArray` as a global, so declare it as one:

```
var imgArray;

function initialize(){
    //add our 10 images to our array 
    imgArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "armory.jpg");
```

Assigning an array literal is a bit easier:

```
    imgArray = [ new ImageItem(imageDir + "armory.jpg"),
                 new ImageItem(imageDir + "eddy.jpg"),
                 ...
                 new ImageItem(imageDir + "...")
    ];
}

var totalImgs = imgArray.length;
```

Though I can't see why you don't just assign the array literal directly and not bother with the wrapper function. The `startImage` function can be a bit tidier:

```
function startImage(){
    document.getElementById("pic").src = imgArray[0].src;
}
```

Accessing element properties directly is more reliable across browsers and less to type than using `setAttribute` (which has quirks in some browsers).

Comment: The ImageItem function and the array being declared as a global helped alot. Thanks

Comment: can you show how i can assign the array without the wrapper function?

Answer (score 3):

Load multiple images sounds like a functionality that you might want to user in different projects. I would suggest to create a function that can process your images array and append the image object to a `<div>`:

```
var images = [
    'path/to/image1.png',
    'path/to/image2.png',
    'path/to/image3.png',
    'path/to/image4.png',
    'path/to/image5.png'
];

function loadImages(imgArr){
    for(var i=0; i< imgArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(imgArr[i]);
        var img = new Image();
            img.src = imgArr[i];
        document.getElementById('output').appendChild(img);
    }
}
                
loadImages(images);
```

You can also invoke the `loadImage()` function from your button:

```
<button onclick="loadImages(images)">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your javascript function like this and see.

```
function startImage(){

    document.getElementById("pic").src =  imgArray[0].src;
}
```