# Calling a class with symbolic name

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

**EDIT:** I would like to implement it with Jekyll, which (as far as I know) does not have PHP, jQuery, and so on...

---

I have a simple problem with CSS; it must have a simple solution but I just don't find it.

Suppose one has multiple `div`s with some classes:

```
<div class="cat">
<div class="dog">
<div class="bird">
<div class="snake">
...
```

and in a `.css` we want to style these 'pet' `div`s; the style is very similar from class to class (for instance we have some photos `cat.jpg`, `dog.jpg`... and want to show them). Can this be achieved by a somewhat symbolic method? Something like

```
div.pet{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url("/pictures/pet.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
    ...
```

(but there is no `class="pet"` nor `pet.jpg`)

Comment: Do you want to change the src of an image element or is a background oke?

Comment: @SvenB Well, yes, background... it was to have an idea, but I'll edit the post. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use sass:

```
div {
  $list: "cat", "dog", "frog";
  // generate classes for list elements
  @each $element in $list {
    &.#{$element} {
    background-image: url('images/#{$element}.jpg');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would have suggested this, too, but the questioner will need to decide if SASS is the answer since SASS generates CSS but is not CSS itself.

Comment: anyway sass is better than JQ or JS as it is a CSS precompiler. It is easy to use sass and you have much better result (bullet proof) than with JS. It is said that sass is extended css also it have backwards compatibility.

Comment: @FrontMonkey Thanks!! I'll try to implement your aproach :)

Comment: simplest way to use sass if it is installed sass "input.scss output.css" You can watch for changes with flag --watch. More info is on sass page http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to add different images sources to the image tags with pure CSS. You may need to use ***JS, JQuery, PHP ,*** etc.

You may do this using JavaScript/JQuery as follows :

Store all the image names in an array and then run a loop on-load(of page) to get images by using those array element(values).

Using **jQuery**, you may set `img` source like this:

```
$("img:nth-child(i)").attr('src', <new path from array[i th element]>);
```

The `nth-child(i)` means `i`th image.

Using Js, you may do this:

```
var images = [
    'path/to/image1.png',
    'path/to/image2.png',
    'path/to/image3.png',
    'path/to/image4.png',
    'path/to/image5.png'
];

function loadImages(imgArr, targetId){
    for(var i=0; i< imgArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(imgArr[i]);
        var img = new Image();
            img.src = imgArr[i];
        document.getElementById('output').appendChild(img);
    }
}

loadImages(images);
```

You can also invode the loadImage() function from yout button:

```
<button onclick="loadImages(images)">Start</button>
```

Refer : [JavaScript load Images in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287091/javascript-load-images-in-an-array-and-show-in-image-source)

Comment: The question asks how to do this with CSS.

Comment: And that is the answer to the question.

Comment: Added that to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your asking But as far as I understand you want to have some global setting for div elements and change the background image:

https://jsfiddle.net/shtjab2k/

Css

```
     #pets > div
  {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    border:2px solid black;
    float:left;
  }

  .cat
  {
    background-image: url("https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300.jpg");
  }
  .bird
  {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/2000px-Solid_blue.svg.png");
  }
```

html

```
<div id="pets">
 <div class="cat "></div>
 <div class="dog "></div>
 <div class="bird "></div>
 <div class="snake "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The point is to avoid a very long list in css, specially if adding lots of pets in html and images but no change in the css wanted

Comment: @jekyll-friend see my updated answer, now you dont have to use pet for every pet.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something you can do with CSS. CSS can only style objects and can't make other changes/additions/deletions of DOM objects.

But it is definitely something you can do with jQuery! If you know that you always have a class name `class="cat"` that is the same as the file name `cat.jpg`, you can do something like this:

```
$("div").each(function(){
   var petClass = this.attr('class');
   var petImg = petClass + ".jpg";
   this.append("<img src='"+petImg+"' ... >");
});
```

Comment: Is this implementable in jekyll?

Comment: Yes I think so. You just add jquery like this:  <script type="text/javscript" src="/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Comment: I've never used jekyll, but other people have added jquery:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502943/using-jquery-with-jekyll-site-hosted-on-github-pages

Comment: Same idea here, just insert jquery as the "src": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118780/trouble-linking-external-javascript-with-jekyll

Comment: @jekyll-friend did any of these suggestions help you? Could you mark one as the answer, or let us know better how we can help?

Comment: All the comments are good; the one with sass seems to be a good start. I would vote your answers because they're really helpful, but I have not enough points yet :( ...

Comment: @jekyll-friend That's okay! I don't have much rep myself yet ;)  Just so you know, SASS compiles into a static CSS sheet just like any other. It ends up being the same as if you typed out the static CSS yourself. So if you're trying to add components your DOM dynamically (on the client side) you'll have to use a different solution. Thanks for accepting an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, pure-css way to do this is this:

```
.dog, .cat, .bird, .snake {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("/pictures/pet.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

It doesn't matter that the background we provide doesn't exist, we'll replace it in the css for individual pet types:

```
.dog {
  background-image: url("/pictures/dog.jpg");
}
```

It seems like you're looking for a way to do this in a single ruleset, which, unfortunately, is not possible. For that, you'd have to look into using Javascript or a CSS superset (see other answers on this post).

Otherwise, you can just write a couple more lines of css and set the background image for each pet type. =P

Comment: The OP wants to do it all at once. His example in the question is this!