# Is SASS dynamic or static?

Tags: css, sass

I've never used SASS before, and have been reading both on the website as well as some SO questions... but I want to make sure I have it right!

Here's my undersanding:

- You write some SASS code with variables etc...
- You compile the SASS into CSS
- Then you take that static CSS and put it on your website

This means that SASS can dynamically create complex CSS sheets for you, but once you compile, that's it. It's static.

So no dynamic reordering or addition to the DOM like is possible with scripting languages. Am I on target here?

If so, I'm not sure why I would use it and would love to hear from someone who LOVES SASS to tell me their use case! ;)

***Context***

I was helping someone here: [Calling a class with symbolic name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035403/calling-a-class-with-symbolic-name/37035652#37035652)

He decided to go with a SASS solution, and I wanted to make sure I understood what that meant.

Comment: Sass is nothing more than a more convenient way to write boilerplate CSS.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic reordering or addition to Dom?

Comment: I mean with something like jQuery I can change anything I want client side at run time... styles, append text, new DOM objects, etc...

Comment: Let's make it more clear. With sass you can also make javascript Dom manipulation. Sass compiler only transforms your sass file in a regular css. So you can make all the Dom and style manipulation you want at run time. The browser doesn't care if your stylesheets are compiled or not.

Comment: So the browser compiles Sass for you?

Comment: SASS is at the end of its lifecycle, much like jQuery. It was invented to iron out wrinkles in writing CSS most of which no longer exist. It promotes a style of rule writing which is hard to read, write, and maintain. It requires extra build steps. If you attempts to use its more advanced features such as macros, then now you have another language to learn and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS can make writing CSS a lot like coding wherein you can use variables and functions and also you can have selectors written in a beautiful manner..

Definitely a far better option than just writing pure CSS..

But it is static..

Comment: Thanks Dhaval!  Do you use SASS yourself? Does it really speed up the process that much?  I don't want to miss out on something awesome! ;)

Comment: yes .. I use SASS and it makes writing CSS a lot more logical and if you get the hang of it .. it actually makes it faster and your code more concise..so if you have time..just go thru the alecaddd crash course on SASS on youtube ( 5 -6 min videos and around 6-7 videos ) to see if its worth your time to go into more details..

Comment: Thanks again. Those were informative. For anyone else interested here's a link to the videos: https://youtu.be/ok3y4E5NEmw